# Analytic Function such that $f(2z) = 4\,f(z)$

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-functions

> Let $f \colon \mathbb{C} \longrightarrow \mathbb{C}$ such that $f(2z) = 4\,f(z)$, for all $z \in \mathbb{C}$. Given that $f(0) = 0$ and $f(1) = 1 + 2i$, find $f(\sqrt{2} + i\,\sqrt{2})$.

My attempt was to write $f(z) = \sum a_n\,z^n$ and plug in the conditions, i.e.,
$$\sum a_n\,2^n\,z^n = \sum 4\,a_n\,z^n$$ which gives $a_n\,2^n = 4\,a_n$, but this didn't help at all... 
How would I start this question? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The $a_n2^n=4a_n$ implies that $a_n=0$ for all $n\neq 2$. And so your function is simply $f(z)=az^2$. And then the "$f(1)=1+2i$" condition gives you $a$. Although the "$f(0)=0$" condition is weird. It seems to be redundant. Are you sure that the domain is $\mathbb{C}$, i.e. that $f$ is entire?

Comment: Thank you! It was really simple after all. The question only says that $f \colon \mathbb{C} \longrightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is analytic, for all $z \in \mathbb{C}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$a_n\,2^n = 4\,a_n$ helps a *lot*, actually. It tells you almost all you need to know. For which $n$ is $a_n\neq0$ at all possible?

Comment: Thank you, Arthur! 
It was really helpful, the only $n$ such that $a_n \neq 0$ is $n = 2$, so it reduces to a quadratic function. Really good!